# Notion Sobolev space (multiindices notion)

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

While studying Sobolev spaces the following notion/fact comes up and I do not see the triviality. Perhaps someone can give some lines to this notion and in particular to this $L^p$-space notion:

Let $\Sigma_k = \{\alpha: \vert\alpha\vert \leq k\}$ and consider

$W^{k,p}(U) \ni f\rightarrow (f_\alpha)_{\vert\alpha \vert\leq k}\in L^p(U \times\Sigma_k)$

This should be a isometry for obvious reasons. Why?

Comment: Do you mean $L^p(U \times \Sigma_k)$ or $\Pi_{\alpha \in \Sigma_k} L^p(U)$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. They're isomorphic, so doesn't really matters.

Comment: Of course, but the notation in the OP seems to indicate the latter.

Comment: Would the latter notation makes sense to you?